# FrameLayout : Can i send a photo using socket?

Tags: android, sockets, send, android-framelayout

Displays an image from the camera to `FrameLayout`.
Can this picture be sent using socket?

```
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);     
preview.addView(mPreview);
```

As such can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: please share more info on your problem ...

Comment: How to stretch the image of FrameLayout